# error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

tengo este código y cuando ejecuto me sale el error del titulo,no se que significa ,ni se que es ,ni se si es un error de código o un error del compilador ,alguien sabe como podría solucionar este error ,tambien adjunto una imagen con el error por si alguien sabe que pueda ser o como solucionarlo ,ley alguna y me dice que puede ser talves error al llamar la funcion
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[image: error std:]

```
 #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <time.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void aleatory_ip(long ip){
    
     volatile int n1[ip];
     volatile int n2[ip];
     volatile int n3[ip];
     volatile int n4[ip];
    
     int t  = 0;
     int j  = 0;
     int k  = 0;
    
     string IPs[ip];
     string IPc[ip];
     string IPa[ip];
    
      for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
         
        
        n1[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
        n2[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
        n3[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
        n4[i] = 0 + rand() % 255;
    
      }
    
      
                j = 0;
                k = 0;
                t = 0;
    
      for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
        
       IPs[i] = to_string(n1[i]) + '.' +
                to_string(n2[i]) + '.' + 
                to_string(n3[i]) + '.' + 
                to_string(n4[i]) ;
              
      }
      
              for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
                 
                  if (IPs[i] =="127.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="0.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="3.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="15.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="56.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="10.0.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="192.168.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="172.16.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else if (IPs[i] =="100.64.0.0")
                 {
                   continue;
                 }
                 else{
        
                   IPs[i] = IPa[i];
                   j++;
        
                 }
        
               }
    
    
            
         
                    j = 0;
    
            for(int i = 0; i < ip; i++){
    
              for(j = i + 1; j < ip; j++){
    
                if(IPs[i] == IPs[j]){
     
                     k = j;
     
                     while(k < ip){
    
                        IPs[k] = IPs[k+1]; 
     
                        ++k;
                    }
     
                    --ip;
                    --j;
     
                
                  }
     
                }
     
             }
     
    
             for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
    
              t = sizeof(IPs[i]);
    
             }
    
              system("color 6");
    
             for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i){
    
                cout<<"[server:]"<<IPs[i]<<endl;
    
             }
            cout<<"[server:]"<<t;
        
    
    }
    void test_case(){
    
      long T;
      cin>>T;
      aleatory_ip(T);
    
    
     }
    int main(){
    
    
     test_case();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

[image: error no me muestra por pantalla]

Comment: Has hecho esta pregunta varias veces y varias veces se te ha pedido que corrijas varios problemas de tu código que sigues manteniendo pregunta, tras pregunta, tras pregunta, tras pregunta. ¿De verdad **lees** lo que la gente te escribe? Por favor, no nos hagas perder el tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varios problemas en el código:

```
void aleatory_ip(long ip){

 volatile int n1[ip];
```

**volatile** es una palabra reservada que le dice al compilador que no intente optimizar los usos de esta variable ya que puede ser modificada en cualquier momento por otro hilo (de no usarla podrías acabar recuperando valores antiguos de la variable). No utilizas multihilo en esta sección, así que esa palabra reservada sobra

**VLA**: `int n1[ip]`. Los arrays son unas estructuras que se crean en la **pila del programa**. Por definición, su tamaño es fijo y debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación. `ip` es una variable, por lo que su tamaño solo se puede determinar en tiempo de ejecución. Esta característica, conocida como **V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray, **no** está soportada por el estándar y presenta varios problemas:

- La pila es una región de memoria de tamaño finito y fijo. Si se desborda, el programa muere. Esto quiere decir que meter ahí elementos que ocupen mucha memoria no es buena idea.
- Que tu compilador soporte una característica que no pertenece al estándar no implica que dicha característica se comporte como tu esperas, si no te informas bien sobre cómo debe usarse en ese compilador puede darte problemas.
- Los arrays se almacenan en la pila
- ¿Qué sucedería si `ip==0`? ¿y si `ip<0`?

Para estos usos que pretendes, usa `new[]` y `delete[]`:

```
int * n1 = new int[ip];

// ...

delete[] n1;
```

> he hecho las correcciones que has dicho ,sigue sin funcionar

Es el precio a pagar por escribir fuera de los límites de un array:

```
while(k < ip){

    IPs[k] = IPs[k + 1]; 
 
    ++k;
}
```

`IPs`  tiene valores en el rango (0, ip-1), cuando `k==ip-1`, entonces `k+1==ip` y ahí estás escribiendo fuera de los límites del array. Hay que reducir las iteraciones del array en una unidad:

```
 while(k < ip - 1){

    IPs[k] = IPs[k+1]; 

    ++k;
}
```

Con esos cambios a mi me compila y se ejecuta, aunque no sale ninguna IP lógica, eso sería motivo para una nueva pregunta

Comment: ,gracias ,voy a intentarlo ,haber si mi programa funciona

Comment: una duda si yo pongo a ip como variable de tipo const funcionara

Comment: he hecho las correcciones que has dicho ,sigue sin funcionar

Comment: gracias ,ya no me aparece ese error pero no me muestra por pantalla el arreglo que puede hacer ,edite la pregunta y te muestro lo que me aparece

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo arreglar todo el código daría como resultado una respuesta demasiado larga. Ya te compila, mira primero a ver si eres capaz de encontrar los errores por ti mismo

Comment: gracias ,lo voy a intentar a ver que error puede ser en el codigo

Comment: ,podrias botar esta pregunta positivamente